# C# xUnit member data getting data twice

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, xunit.net

I have simple test project using xUnit. When I return new instance of a class (new `LinkConfig`) inside `GetTestData` method.
So while debugging, `GetTestData` method **is called twice** before all tests run. But it works fine if I return string instead of a new instance of a class.

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(GetTestData))]
public void Test(LinkConfig config)
{ 
//Arrange
var url = config.Url;

//Act & Assert 
Assert.Equal("http://google.com", url); 
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetTestData()
{  
var config = new LinkConfig { Url = "http://google.com" }; 
yield return new object[] { config }; 
}
```

Comment: Are you simply triggering evaluation via the debugger? i.e. if you had a watch which called the generator etc. And what is your actual problem - you say "it works fine..." - what's not fine about what's happening?

Comment: Yes, i forgot to set question. I have no use to return a simple string. I need to return a class. But i if return a class, MemberData getting test data twice. How to prevent it to do it that way? GetTestData must calls once.

Comment: You still havent ruled out that the double iteration is triggered by your use of the debugger. The code as-is is perfectly normal and xUnit will not double iterate itself. But if you have a watch etc. then it's perfectly possible - debuggers make things happen. Back to the question - so what if this does happen - if there is a missile you only want to launch once, you could initialize an array field and target the MemberData at that etc.